# Is the Repository Pattern appropriate to communicate with a device on a Serial Port

Tags: design-patterns, serial-port, repository-pattern

I need to create an application that will communicate with a device via the SerialPort

Is the Repository Pattern appropriate with this?

Answer (score 0):

The Repository pattern is more appropriate for code that will be used to store data as opposed to communicating messages.

Communication with a device over a serial port might best be served by a Publisher-Subscriber design pattern. Your messages would be published by the application, and a serial port subscriber would receive these messages, and handle serial port specific commands.

Of course, there is likely to be more than one pattern that will meet your requirements, but you must decide which one works best for your scenario.